# Best way to update object with react redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I would like to know what is the best way to update object with react redux.

Currently, I have this :

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

...

const { postForm } = useSelector((state) => ({
    ...state.postReducer,
}));

const dispatch = useDispatch();

const handleProperty = (property, value) => {
    dispatch({
        type: "UPDATE_POST_FORM",
        payload: {[property]: value}
    })
};
```

In my "template" :

```
<input value={postForm.title} onChange={event => handleProperty('title', event.target.value)} />
```

In my reducer :

```
// State
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    postForm: null,
};

// Mutations
const UPDATE_POST_FORM = (state, payload) => {
    return {
        ...state,
        companyForm: {...state.companyForm, ...payload},
    };
};

// Actions
function postReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'UPDATE_POST_FORM': {
            return UPDATE_POST_FORM(state, action.payload);
        }
    }

    return state;
}

export default postReducer;
```

With vuejs, it's very easy to update the model with v-model.

With react is more complex, and I would like to know if this way is the best way.

So, I write this on each input or there is an alternative to write better, for example, an equivalent v-model (vuejs), with redux, or react to read/write the state directly ?

```
<input value={postForm.date} onChange={event => handleProperty('date', event.target.value)} />

<input value={postForm.description} onChange={event => handleProperty('description', event.target.value)} />

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Redux is based on immutability so just update the state object making sure that the object instance you return is a new one. Assuming the part of the state that you want to change is `postForm`, it would be something like:

```
function postReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'UPDATE_POST_FORM': {
            return { ...state, postForm: action.payload };
        }
    }

    return state;
}
```

And that should do it.

As a suggestion, immutability is not important in selector, since you are only slicing off the part of the state you're interested in, so I would recommend you to just do:

```
const { postForm } = useSelector((state) => state.postReducer;
```

It's a minor performance improvement too, no need to create a new instance there.

Comment: Thank you @David for your answer, my question was about the write in "template" : I write this on each input or there is an alternative to write better ? Thank you for your recommandation !